# Como limitar a quantidade de 'checkbox' selecionados?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Tenho um `form` com 5 (cinco) `checkbox`. Gostaria que o usuário apenas pudesse marcar 3 (três) desses 5 (cinco).

Como faço para fazer essa validação usando jQuery ou Bootstrap?

Valeu a todos pela colaboração.

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(function(){
  var MAX_SELECT = 3; // Máximo de 'input' selecionados
  
  $('input.limited').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).siblings(':checked').length >= MAX_SELECT ){
       this.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><strong>Selecione 3 opções:</strong></p>
<input class='limited' type='checkbox'/> Opção A <br>
<input class='limited' type='checkbox'/> Opção B <br>
<input class='limited' type='checkbox'/> Opção C <br>
<input class='limited' type='checkbox'/> Opção D <br>
<input class='limited' type='checkbox'/> Opção E <br>
```

**Link útil**: <kbd>[.sibilings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)</kbd>